# Which Commerce module to use?

Tags: commerce

I'm creating a website that only has one product (credits to enable them to contact matching users), but want users to be able to buy multiple credits if desired and to be able to track how many have been used.  I don't need to use Kickstart as I don't need a storefront.  Is there a way to set this up in Commerce or can someone point me to a tutorial that just has a simple setup?

Answer (score 1):

Commerce has reported installs: 65,052, Ubercart has reported installs: 37,622, commerce is best updated and there are more sub-modules avilable . On both, simple payment method is not so easy, everything is editable: amount, price, whatever. My humble advise is go with commerce.